# iOS - AVPlayer.currentItem.accessLog.events empty for audio live stream

Tags: xcode, avplayer, avplayeritem

AVPlayer has a useful documented feature called accessLog that makes it possible to diagnose buffer size, data consumption and other parameters during playback.

The problem is that for audio live stream the access log contains no events at all and I'm not able to find any information on why is that?

Tried on multiple platforms:

XCode Swift:

```swift
let lastEvent = self.avPlayer.currentItem.accessLog.events.last     // = nil
```

Visual Studio Xamarin iOS:

```
var lastEvent = this.avPlayer.CurrentItem.AccessLog.Events.Length   // = 0
```

Any ideas why is that?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this ? I notice the same thing

Comment: No, unfortunately no and I have no idea how to contact Apple about this :( They seem like a fortress, no contact info...